# Google Login button in Blazor Server .NET 8 : OAuth state missing

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, google-signin, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I am using identity scaffolding in a .NET 8 Blazor server app. I have login with Google working in the Identity pages, but cannot login through a provided Google button.

I can click the button, login to Google, but then see this error on the site:

> AuthenticationFailureException: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
> Unknown location

`LoginDisplay.razor`:

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor ContextAccessor

<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Manage">Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!</a>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Logout">Log out</a>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Register">Register</a>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Login">Log in</a>

        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="MY KEY"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="redirect"
     data-login_uri="https://localhost:7257/signin-google"
     data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
@code
{
    string Id = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var x = ContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
        var xIdentity = x.Identity;
    }
}
```

I tried adding the sample Google Login button from Googles site, and linked it to my login callback URI, expecting the user to login as if it was through the login page

Answer (score 0):

The root cause for this issue is you are missing `state`. In the OAuth process, the state parameter is an important security feature used to prevent CSRF (cross-site request forgery) attacks.

And a find [a good sample](https://github.com/googleworkspace/browser-samples/blob/3eb387306756dae742e3374c26fc1053312f2ac0/drive/picker/helloworld.html#L52) for you, hope you can refer it to change your code.